# Angular call different controller methods for different urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, seo, single-page-application

I have a single page application in which the footer contains multiple links for About, FAQs, Privacy etc. Currently i am using angular-strap modal to show a modal for each link. The code for that looks like as follows:

```
 <li>
     <a href="#about" id="about" 
     data-modal-class="my_modal gradient-body"
     data-bs-modal="'templates/about.html'">About
     </a>
 </li>
```

So currently the url of my application won't change on clicking About link. It will simply launch the modal . 
Now i want to keep the functionality same but have a url like mydomain.com/#about to launch the about box.

I am using $routeProvider to define routes as follows:

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map.html'      
    })
    .when('/verify/:code',{
      template : " ",
      controller : 'VerifyReportCtrl'
    })    
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

The reason why i want to do it is because it will help in SEO of my application. Currently there is no way to index the About page content.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your route as

```
 $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/map.html'      
    })
    .when('/verify/:code',{
      template : " ",
      controller : 'VerifyReportCtrl'
    })    
    .when('/about',{
      template : "templates/about.html "
    })  
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

And change HTML as

```
 <li>
     <a href="#about" id="about" 
     data-modal-class="my_modal gradient-body">About
     </a>
 </li>
```

Then if you click on anchor tag your url will look like  `mydomain.com/#about`

Comment: I doesn't work .It will try to load about.html is the current ng-view. But i want to load it in the modal which was earlier being done through data-bs-modal="'templates/about.html'"